# ImageResizer SqlReader Plugin redirects to Account/login page

Tags: imageresizer

When using the ImageResizer SqlReader Plugin I get redirected to the Account/Login Page when I request for Images. I cant trace my problem since my plugin and web.config is correctly configured as in the demos and sample configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you have an authorization systems preventing them from being accessed.

If you want all images to be publicly accessible, you need to exclude those directories from URL Authorization module (or whichever system is responsible for sending out the 403/redirect).

ImageResizer simply follows whatever rules you have the application under.

Comment: I completely forgot to thank you for your solution. It worked well and have been using it for a few months now. Thank you.